# How do I set Frame.Navigate to happen immediately with no transition?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app as part of a Windows Universal App. Following the tutorial on [extending splash screens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868191(v=win.10).aspx) in Windows Universal Apps I changed my App.xaml.cs to replace

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SplashPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create splash page");
}
```

with

```
if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
{
    var extendedSplash = new SplashPage(e.SplashScreen);
    Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
}
```

However this meant that I lost access to the root frame when I overwrote `Window.Current.Content`. I would like to instead use

```
SplashPage.SplashScreen = e.SplashScreen;
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SplashPage), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create splash page");
}
```

But now the page transitions in. There is an override for [`Frame.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279553.aspx) which takes an additional `NavigationTransitionInfo` parameter, typically set to one of its subclasses:

1. [CommonNavigationTransitionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.commonnavigationtransitioninfo.aspx) (i.e. roll in from the right);
2. [SlideNavigationTransitionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.slidenavigationtransitioninfo.aspx) (i.e. slides up); or
3. [ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.continuumnavigationtransitioninfo.aspx) (i.e. a short zoom-in).

(N.B. James Croft has a good [blog post](http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/windows-phone-dev/utilizing-page-transition-animations-in-windows-phone-8-1-apps/) showing these transitions.)

But for a splash screen extension I need the page to show immediately, without a transition (just as one gets by overwriting `Window.Current.Content` with the new page instance).

How do I set `Frame.Navigate` to happen immediately with no transition?

Comment: I think it should work, fi you disable default transitions for a frame - in *app.xaml.cs* file, where the *rootFrame* is created, just after creation, add `rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;`.

Comment: Brilliant. That was already in App.xaml.cs but it lead me on to the Frame.Navigated event where I could change the handler to only add back the transitions if `NavigationEventArgs.SourcePageType != typeof(SplashPage)`

Comment: You may also think of disabling frame's transition and define them for every page in xaml if needed.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to do the same thing for a Windows 10 UWP app, it can be achieved like this:

```
// Navigate to your first page without a transition 
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), null, new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
```

According to [this MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.suppressnavigationtransitioninfo).

Answer (score 3):

I would try to disable default *Frame.ContentTransitions* by setting it to *null*, just after the *rootFrame* is created in *App.xaml.cs* file (don't forget to handle different events - Launched/ShareTarget/Activated - if needed):

```cs
rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null
```

once you have done that, pages shouldn't have transition. Then if you want, you can bring back or set new transitions for *Frame*'s content upon specific circumstances, or set transitions for pages individually, for example in *Page*'s XAML:

```xml
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

Comment: I am using a WebView in a Windows 10 Universal App and the animation was causing a "page load flicker".  Removing <Frame.ContentTransitions> in the AppShell.xaml solved the issue.